# Should mocks be used when unit testing a method that calls other, already unit tested methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a method for validating an object. The validation that should be applied is dependant on some other value(s). Simple Example:

```
public void ValidateObject(Object object, TestEnum enum, bool required)
{
    if(enum == TestEnum.A)
    {
        ValidateObjectPropertyA(object.PropertyA, required);
        ValidateObjectPropertyB(object.PropertyB, required);
        //Other Calls to Validation Methods
    }
    else
    {
        if(enum == TestEnum.C)
        {
            required = false;
        }

        ValidateObjectPropertyC(object.PropertyC, required);
        //Other Calls to Validation Methods
    }
}
```

In the above example, the methods ValidateObjectPropertyA, ValidateObjectPropertyB and ValidateObjectPropertyC are fully unit tested. I am now looking to unit test the "ValidateObject" method.

Given that the 3 methods have been fully unit tested, is this a good situation to use mocks to validate that the correct values are being passed to each method?

Answer (score 0):

Given the ValidateObjectPropertyA/B/C/etc. methods don't have return values I assume the validation fails if they throw an exception, otherwise it's considered success, so you can mock them and take the [interaction-based testing](https://mearnsb.medium.com/to-assert-or-not-to-assert-interaction-based-testing-for-better-or-worse-19c6f7bef827) approach where you verify the mocked methods were invoked with the expected arguments.

If those methods come from an implementation of some interface/abstract class you could mock them with [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) and use [Verify](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#verification) methods to assert methods were called as expected.

If ValidateObjectPropertyA/B/C are private methods of the class that implements ValidateObject then you shouldn't mock them since the unit test shouldn't depend on implementation details of the tested class, and you may want to apply an [Extract Class refactoring](https://refactoring.guru/extract-class) to move ValidateObjectPropertyA/B/C to a new mockable interface `IObjectPropertyValidator`.